# Is there a way to refactor dependend Axios calls to an JSON api?

Tags: node.js, json, api, refactoring, axios

Im currently trying to receive data from an JSON api endpoint and process them further. The main goal is to archive an json file with all data as seperate arrays and convert that into 4 different CSV files. As you can see on the code below im successfully receiving data but due the dependend calls to the api i got sometimes the problem of failing early calls and due that failing more indepth calls.

My question is: Is there a way to successfully refactor that to catch the failing calls and rerun them and there are a ideas to make it more reliable and "cleaner"

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')
const colors = require('colors')

const url = "json.endpoint.url";
const MANDATOR = 1234567890

const TecDoc = []


async function callApi(url, query) {
    let res = await axios.post(url, query);
    let { data } = res.data
    return data.array
}


const getManufacturer = { "getManufacturers": {"country": "DE", "favourdedList": 0, "lang": "de", "linkingTargetType": "P", "provider": MANDATOR} }
let Manufacturer = callApi(url, getManufacturer)
Manufacturer.then(function(ManufacturerResult) {
    for(let i = 0; i < ManufacturerResult.length; i++) {


        var getModelSeries = { "getModelSeries": {"country": "DE", "favourdedList": 0, "lang": "de", "linkingTargetType": "P", "manuId": ManufacturerResult[i].manuId, "provider": MANDATOR}}
        let Model = callApi(url, getModelSeries)
        Model.then(function(ModelResult) {
            if(ModelResult !== undefined) {

                for(let j = 0; j < ModelResult.length; j++) {

                    var getVehicleIdsByCarCriteria = { "getVehicleIdsByCriteria": {"carType": "P", "countriesCarSelection": "DE", "lang": "de", "manuId": ManufacturerResult[i].manuId, "modId": ModelResult[j].modelId, "provider": MANDATOR}}
                    let Car = callApi(url, getVehicleIdsByCarCriteria)
                    Car.then(function(CarResult) {
                        for(let k = 0; k < CarResult.length; k++) {


                            var getVehicleByIds4 = { "getVehicleByIds4": {"articleCountry": "DE", "axles": false, "cabs": false, "carIds": {"array": [CarResult[k].carId]}, "countriesCarSelection": "de", "country": "de", "countryGroupFlag": false, "kbaData": true, "lang": "de", "motorCodes": false, "provider": MANDATOR, "secondaryTypes": false, "wheelBase": false}}
                            let finalCarData = callApi(url, getVehicleByIds4)
                            finalCarData.then(function(Result) {

                                //console.log(Result[0].vehicleDetails.manuName)
                                TecDoc.push(Result)

                                fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(TecDoc), 'utf-8', function() {
                                    console.log("Writing: " + Result[0].vehicleDetails.manuName + " - " + Result[0].vehicleDetails.modelName + " ( " + Result[0].vehicleDetails.typeName + " ) ")
                                })

                            }).catch(function(error) {
                                console.log("FinalCar: ".bold + `${error}`.bgBlue)
                            })


                        }
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("CarType: ".bold + `${error}`.bgYellow.black)
                    })   


                }
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("ModelSeries: ".bold + `${error}`.bgMagenta)
        })


    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Manufacturer: ".bold + `${error}`.bgRed)
})

//CSV.writeRecords(TecDoc).then(() => console.log('✔ ' + 'The Manufacturer CSV file was successfully written'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, you need to modularize your code by making some separate functions that return Promises. Take one array and push that function call for the loop. Let's take a look in this example.

```
// You have requirement to get data from func1 => func2 => func3. If any of once is rejected then throw an error or getting success
const userUtils = {};

userUtils.function1 = (yourInputs) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if (yourInputs) {
  return resolve('f1');
}
return reject();
});
};

userUtils.function2 = (fun1Output) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if (fun1Output) {
  return resolve('f2');
}
return reject();
});
};

userUtils.function3 = (fun2Output) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if (fun2Output) {
  return resolve('f3');
}
return reject();
});
};

userUtils.allFunctionCall = async (input) => {
try {
const resultf1 = await userUtils.function1(input);
const resultf2 = await userUtils.function2(resultf1);
const resultf3 = await userUtils.function3(resultf2);
return resultf3;
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
throw error;
}
};

userUtils.callFunctions = () => {
const array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i += 1) {
// call function here 
array.push(userUtils.allFunctionCall(true));
}

Promise.all(array)
.then((res) => {
  console.log('RES', res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
};

userUtils.callFunctions();

module.exports = userUtils;
```

In the above code, you need to call func3 after func2 and func1 called successfully.
So here we separate function in chanks and call it from single place `userUtils.allFunctionCall()` and call it in for loop, and handle it using `Promise.all()`. Through this, you can easily debug your code and easy to understand for other developers too.

I hope it helps, Happy Coding :)